# The biggest power of $p$ that is smaller than $X$

Tags: calculus

Given a number $X$, then how can I obtain

- wich is the biggest power of $2$ but smaller than $X$?
- which is the biggest power of $3$ but smaller than $X$?
- which is the biggest power of $p$ but smaller than $X$? Knowing of course that $p$ is any prime less than $X$.

I only can get it by using the calculator and trial and error.

Comment: $\lfloor \log_p(x)\rfloor$.

Comment: Using the comment of @ArturoMagidin, $$p^a \leq x < p^{a+1} \implies a \leq \log_p(x) < (a+1) ~: ~a \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$   You also have that $$\log_p(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(p)},$$ where $\log(x)$ refers to the natural logarithm of $(x)$.